# select a json key's value using sql in bigQuery

Tags: sql, json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I run a simple query that returns an output like this:

```
[{
  "polarity": "0.0",
  "magnitude": "2.0",
  "score": "0.5",
  "entities": [{
    "name": "Taubenkot",
    "type": "OTHER",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "1",
    "avgSalience": "0.150263"
  }, {
    "name": "Lösung",
    "type": "OTHER",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "1",
    "avgSalience": "0.145794"
  }, {
    "name": "Busbahnhof",
    "type": "LOCATION",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "1",
    "avgSalience": "0.108006"
  }, {
    "name": "Stadt",
    "type": "LOCATION",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "3",
    "avgSalience": "0.079928"
  }, {
    "name": "Taubenplage",
    "type": "OTHER",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "2",
    "avgSalience": "0.072326"
  }, {
    "name": "Rutschgefahr",
    "type": "OTHER",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "1",
    "avgSalience": "0.070839"
  },
{
    "name": "Meike Böschemeyer",
    "type": "PERSON",
    "mid": "/g/11btlnnjgf",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "1",
    "avgSalience": "0.00451"
  }]
}]
```

BigQuery automatically shows the different entity key values in separate columns. How can I query a particular key's value?

I was trying this:

```
select JSON_VALUE(entities, '$.type') AS type from gcnlapi limit 1
```

but it gives me this error

```
No matching signature for function JSON_VALUE for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, type STRING, mid STRING, ...>>, STRING. Supported signatures: JSON_VALUE(STRING, [STRING]); JSON_VALUE(JSON, [STRING]) at [3:8]
```

Also tried this:

```
select entities.type AS type from gcnlapi limit 1
```

but that would give me

```
Cannot access field type on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, type STRING, mid STRING, ...>> at [5:17]
```

Comment: entities must be a  string or a json, what exactly is entities in your query, big query does identify it as string or json, also which query gives you that result?

Comment: entities is an array. its is a simple select * from the table. @nbk. i would like to select the name of the entity entry where type is "LOCATION"

Comment: I don’t understand, the json is a result of a column ?

Comment: no the json is the result of my query, displayed under the "json" tab of big query @MazlumTosun

Comment: you need to unnest your array, as you don't have a kson at all see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays?hl=de and the resulting table you can access like normal

Comment: As I understand you want to flatten your array and retrieve fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this example can help you :

```sql
SELECT
    polarity,
    magnitude,
    score,

    name,
    type,
    mid,
    wikipediaUrl,
    numMentions,
    avgSalience
FROM
    `your_project.your_dataset.your_table`,
    UNNEST(entities)
```

With `UNNEST` you can `flatten` your array and get the field at `root` level of the table and also the fields of the array (flattened).

In this query, fields at root level are `polarity`, `magnitude` and `score` and others correspond to the array fields.